# Correct procedure for loging out a user

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive iOS SDK. I can successfully log a user in, store a keychain item so he doesn't have to sign in every time he wants to access his Drive. The app I'm building is multi-user, so I need a way to log-out a user, COMPLETELY remove that user's stored keychain, and handle a new user's authentication.

I've read around, and I've found this:

```
- (IBAction)logoutButton:(id)sender {
   [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch removeAuthFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName];
}
```

The problem is that when trying to authorize a new user it appears that the previous function didn't completely de-authorize the user because this function doesn't present the Log-in View Controller:

```
- (IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender {
if (!self.service.authorizer.canAuthorize) {
    // Not yet authorized, request authorization by pushing the login UI onto the UI stack.
    [self presentViewController:[self createAuthController] animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

}

Am I missing something to correctly remove a user's authentication/authorization from my app? Or should I be handling it differently?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my app, if keep GTLServiceDrive's authorizer value, you need set authorizer = nil;

following code in my logout method,

```
[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch removeAuthFromKeychainForName:keychainItemName];
        [GTLServiceDrive sharedServiceDrive].authorizer = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can try using the [**signOut**](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in#sign_out_the_user) method of the GPPSignIn object to sign out your user. It removes the OAuth 2.0 token from the keychain.
Example:

```
- (void)signOut {
  [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
}
```

Then as discussed in the documentation, you must offer users who signed in with Google the ability to disconnect from your app. If the user deletes their account, you must delete the information that your app obtained from the Google APIs.

Sample code to programmatically revoke access tokens that your app was granted on behalf of the user and to disconnect the user's account from your app.

```
- (void)disconnect {
  [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] disconnect];
}

- (void)didDisconnectWithError:(NSError *)error {
  if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Received error %@", error);
  } else {
    // The user is signed out and disconnected.
    // Clean up user data as specified by the Google+ terms.
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the info, I followed the link you provided, and found that it's been deprecated.